# Xcode 8.0 beta missing required architecture x86_64 while building on simulator

Tags: x86-64, xcode8

When i tried to build the project on simulator xcode 8 throws error "missing required architecture x86_64" for most of the libraries

like am using gdata, googleanalytics
i did lipo -info for both
libGDataTouchStaticLib.a : armv7 i386 arm64 
libGoogleAnalytics.a : armv7 armv7s i386

Here gdata is throwing above error but googleanalytics works

And when i tried to build on device with ios10 it build without errors