# Xcode 8.1 - missing required architecture x86_64 while building on simulator

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-simulator, xcode8

while i'm trying to build my project (on simulator) i'm getting an error which says : [image]

as you can see that my error is occurring in [this class](http://pastebin.com/b2Q21MBf) ,  but when i'm building my project on a real device all errors are gone dont know whats wrong here.

if anybody knows then let me know how can i fix it...

P.S.  we do have a similar question right 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268219/xcode-8-0-beta-missing-required-architecture-x86-64-while-building-on-simulator) but that question didn't got any attention and my case is a bit different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 6.1 Missing required architecture X86\_64 in file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552855/xcode-6-1-missing-required-architecture-x86-64-in-file)